# Shopify Liquid Date Beginning of the year variables

Tags: date, shopify, liquid

I am looking to create variables for the following:

1. The Beginning of this Year: Example if the date is 5/3/2021 then this would be 2021-01-05
2. The Beginning of last year: Example if in 2021 then the date would be 2020-01-01
3. The End of Last year:  Example if in 2021 then the date would be 2020-12-31
4. The beginning of Last Month: Example, if the date is 5/3/2021 then the this would be 2021-04-01
5. The End of last month: Example, if the date is 5/3/2021 then this would be 2021-04-31

I have the following and it shows as expected but I am not sure how I can get these assigned as variables using the liquid syntax.

`{% assign start_date = 'now' | date: '%s' %}`

`{% assign start_date_year = 'now' | date: '%Y' %}`

This shows the date as expected and the year of the current date as well. But when I do the following I do not get the year 2020:

`{% assign yoy_start = start_date_year | minus: 1 | date: '%Y-%m-%d' %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The year alone is not a valid date string that can be parsed by the `date` format. You need something like "Jan 1st, 2020".

Here's a way to do it with the date format

```
{% liquid
assign this_year = 'now' | date: '%Y' 
assign last_year = this_year | minus: 1
assign last_year_start = "Jan 1st, " | append: last_year | date: '%Y-%m-%d'
%}

{{ last_year_start }}
// 2020-01-01
```

But it might be easier to just do

```
{% liquid
assign this_year = 'now' | date: '%Y' 
assign last_year_start = this_year | minus: 1 | append: '-01-01'
%}

{{ last_year_start }}
// 2020-01-01
```

#### Added month example

Here's an example that can find the previous month (and accounts for the previous month being in a previous year)

```
{% liquid 
assign list_of_months = "12,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12" | split: ","
assign last_month_index = 'now' | date: '%m' | minus: 1
assign last_month_year = 'now' | date: '%Y'
if last_month_index < 1
  assign last_month_year = last_month_year | minus: 1
endif
assign last_month_start = last_month_year | append: '-' | append: list_of_months[last_month_index] | append: '-01' 
%}

{{ last_month_start }}
// 2020-04-01
```

#### N.B.

Note that Shopify caches the rendered theme view, so using 'now' can sometimes produce unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you! This worked!  Last thing, I am trying to also bring in the last month based on the current month. I have this built using the same logic that you have for last year, however when it comes to single digit months there will be no '0' before the month number and if I hardcode the 0 then the double digit months would look like 012, so I do not want to do that.
`{% liquid
assign this_month = 'now' | date: '%m' 
assign last_month = this_month | minus: 1
assign last_month_start = this_year | append: '-'| append: last_month | append: '-01'
%}

{{ last_month_start }}
2021-4-01
`

Comment: That gets a bit hairier because you have to account for crossing years, but I've updated my answer with an example to handle months. I did it by creating an array of months with the correct digits, and then using a look up. So if it's January minus a month, then it will subtract 1 from the year too. It's crude but it works because 12 months are predictable, you'd have to take a different strategy to deal with days.